# Speeding Up the Ribbon in Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, ribbon

Has anyone found a Registry Hack or some other way of making the ribbon in Microsoft Office faster? I'm talking about load time. On every computer I've ever used Office 2007 or 2010 there is a slight delay (from half a second to several seconds) when switching tabs in the ribbon or expanding the ribbon when it is collapsed. I think it's doing a lazy load of the ribbon contents, but I would prefer a slightly larger footprint with snappy performance.

*edit*

**I've noticed the delay only occurs the first time I switch to any tab in the ribbon. After that it is, as expected, instantaneous. This is why, as I indicated above, I think Office is doing a Lazy Load of the contents for the ribbon. I think the solution is to tell Office to pre-load instead of lazy-load, but I don't know of any setting for that.**

Any thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, there is no perceptible delay in drawing the ribbon on initial load or tab-switch on my Dell Latitude D620 running Win 7 and Office 2007.

Comment: Even the first load should be fast by default, something is slowing it down...

Answer (score 6):

The slow response could be caused by add-ins.

To check this out, just turn off all of them. Here are the instructions for Word 2007:

1. While logged-in as Administrator, click on the Logo button (upper left
   corner).
2. Click on Word Options on the bottom right.
3. Select Add-ins in the left panel.
4. At the bottom of the window click on
   the Go button (Manage: COM Add-ins)
5. Uncheck all add-ins
6. Click on OK.
7. Exited and restart Word

If this solves the problem, you can turn back on add-ins that you would like to keep (one-by-one, just in case).

As a side remark: This will also save you some memory.

Answer (score 3):

The Ribbon is supposed to switch lightning fast, which makes tips to speed it up non-existant.

Try these things:

- Disable any security software like firewalls and virus scanners to see if they interrupt the ribbon.
- Try to install Microsoft Office again.
- Scan for viruses that might slow down Office.
- Make sure you have the latest drivers.
- If all else fails, reinstall?
- If everything is slow, improve the hardware?

I have Googled for tips and people with similar experience but found nothing,
we can't help you more than trying to get you to the default Office Ribbon experience.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switching between tabs you can create a new own Group tab and add you fav. option in it.

In word 2010:

Click on File tab > Options and select "Customize Ribbon option" on the left panel. or you can follow this to [add custom tab in word 2010](http://www.trickyways.com/2010/06/add-custom-tab-and-group-in-word-2010-ribbon/)

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question. No matter how well we design a custom ribbon there will still be the pain point of horrid delays when we do have to switch between them.

Comment: @theo sometimes there is no answer or the answer is that it's not possible. In those cases, it's good to be open to work-arounds.